# "set" syntax in CMake

Tags: syntax, cmake, set

I am trying to learn CMake from http://www.cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/. I don't follow how `set` syntax works. 
For example, from this tutorial,

```
set (EXTRA_LIBS ${EXTRA_LIBS} MathFunctions)
```

I could understand that here we want to assign `MathFunctions` to the `EXTRA_LIBS` variable. 
But what I am confusing is why we want to have `EXTRA_LIBS ${EXTRA_LIBS}`.
Why not just

```
set (EXTRA_LIBS MathFunctions)
```

Moreover, I test with following code

```
set (VALUE_1 "value 1")  # A
set (VALUE_2 ${VALUE_2} "value 2")  # B

message("value 1:" ${VALUE_1})
message("value 2:" ${VALUE_2})
```

in this case, both # A and # B produce same format of result.

So my question is what is difference between # A and # B?

Comment: It's so that `EXTRA_LIBS` will be set to its current value *and* `MathFunctions` appended. E.g. if `EXTRA_LIBS` is `foo bar` then `set (EXTRA_LIBS ${EXTRA_LIBS} MathFunctions)` expands to `set (EXTRA_LIBS foo bar MathFunctions)` thus setting `EXTRA_LIBS` to `foo bar MathFunctions`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`So my question is what is difference between # A and # B`

In first case `#A` you assign `"value 1"` to variable `VALUE_1`, but in second case you assign to variable `VALUE_2` already existed value of this variable which is concatenated with `"value 2"`.

For example:

```
set (VALUE_1 "default value")
set (VALUE_2 "default value")

set (VALUE_1 "value 1")  # A
set (VALUE_2 ${VALUE_2} "value 2")  # B

message("value 1:" ${VALUE_1})
message("value 2:" ${VALUE_2})
```

Output:

```
...
value 1:value 1
value 2:default valuevalue 2
...
```

Another words the second case is the way to modify already existed variable.

It can be useful when you don't want overwrite existed value, for instance:

MainProject/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set (CXX_COMPILER_FLAG "some optimization flags")
add_subdirectory (SubProject)
```

MainProj/SubProject/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set (CXX_COMPILER_FLAG "some warning flags") #<- wrong, overwrite flags.
set (CXX_COMPILER_FLAG "${CXX_COMPILER_FLAG} some warning flags") #<- correct, safe existed flags and add new flags.
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
set (var_a "value a") # just like: var_a = "value a"
set (var_b ${var_b} "value b") # just like: var_b = var_b + "value b"
```